# Value of variable changes in two diffrent calls in diffrent Html files, but JS file is same

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase

So, I have made this array and made it a var type. When user clicks submit in LOGIN.html, the data is pushed in the DATA_ array. now, I want to use that data in another html file. Lets say I want to make the arrays[1] as my heading. But when I access the function/ DATA_ in my other api.html, it shows that DATA_ is still empty, which makes sense cause original vale is empty only. How do I fix it?
I also want the api.html to only open if log in was done so how do i set it up.

```
<body>

    <div>

        
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="passsword" name="password" placeholder="password">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="login_btn" onclick="loginForm()" >Submit</button>
        

    </div>
   
    <script src="login.js"></script>
</body>
```

**ABOVE IS LOGIN.HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1 id="head">hi</h1>
    <button onclick="call()">click</button>
    <script src="login.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Above is API.html**

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIpozaSyA_TGCvEOURUERSPpkZbYJLYmbeWEDWFEFWFmlmiAyda",
  authDomain: "csc130-signup.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://csc130-signup-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "csc130-signup",
  storageBucket: "csc130-signup.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "4425656562363111437507636325742528615729702",
  appId: "1:424427234625230:web:fccacbccacbcaabfeagd9635909417ffca220531903f3"
};

// intializing the firebase 

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// refrence for data base below

var signupFormDB = firebase.database().ref('signupForm');

var Data_ = []


  function loginForm() {
    var email = getElementVal('email');
    var password = getElementVal('passsword');

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in
    console.log(userCredential);
    console.log("logged")
    
      // after logged in finding the top threee coins and the name of the person that

      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if(user) {
          signupFormDB.on('value', snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(child => {
              if(child.val().email == email){
                window.coin_one = child.val().coin_one;
                const coin_two = child.val().coin_two;
                const coin_three = child.val().coin_three;
                const name = child.val().name;
                Data_.push(coin_one);
                Data_.push(coin_two);
                Data_.push(coin_three);
                console.log(Data_);
                window.location = 'api.html';
              }    
             
            });
          });     
    }
  });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alert(error);
  });
  }
  const getElementVal = (id) => {
    if (document.getElementById(id) == null){ return 0;}
    else {return document.getElementById(id).value;}
    // return document.getElementById(id).value;
  };

  function call(){
    console.log(DATA_);
  }
```

So like, what and how do i make this work?

I tried playing with ver and let and const but no luck there

Comment: use `local storage` for get data into next page. [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp]

Comment: *** REMOVE YOUR firebaseConfig KEYS from the question ***